# Generate one sample following two different distributions

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

I would like to generate randomly a sample in the interval `[0;1000]` of size `1E4`. But following two different distribution : one in the `[0;1]` interval following an increasing exponential distribution which will generate a bench of values close to `1` with respect to the others close to `0`. And then, after to generate the second part of my sample in the `[1;1000]` interval following an `1/r` distribution.

I think the easier way to do this is to split the global sample in two different samples. But I don't know how to deal with it. I tried to use some distribution of the `scipy` librairy but I didn't find a way to use them properly in order to generate my global sample. What do you think?

Comment: In my opinion, this is an area that `scipy` isn't great at.  When all you want to do is sample one at a time from a distribution, `scipy` distributions are simultaneously, way to heavy, but also not able to be combined flexibly like this.  Probably the easiest thing to do here is to first choose between your regimes with something like `random.random` and then depending on that sample from [0,1] or from [1,1000].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two separate distributions but you need to make sure that the number of samples matches at the boundary point (`r == 1`). So you need to estimate the required number of samples for the left (exp) and right (1/r) distribution. The integrals over the two distributions give the following:

- [integrate exp(r) from 0 to 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28r%29+from+0+to+1): `exp(1) - 1 == 1.7183`
- [integrate 1/r from 1 to 1000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fr+from+1+to+1000): `log(1000)  == 6.9078`

This means the probability for the left distribution at `r = 1` is `exp(1) / 1.7183` and for the right distribution it is `1 / 6.9078`. So this gives a ratio of `ratio = left / right = 10.928`. This means you need to generate `ratio` times more values in the right interval than in the left one in order to end up with the same number of samples at the boundary. Let's say you want to generate `N` samples in total this means you need to generate `N1 = N / (ratio + 1)` samples in the left (exp) interval and `N2 = N * ratio / (ratio + 1)` samples in the right (1/r) interval.

So here's some sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r_max = 1000.0
integral_1 = np.exp(1.0) - 1.0  # 1.7183
integral_2 = np.log(r_max)      # 6.9078

N = 2_000_000  # total number of samples
ratio = np.exp(1.0) / integral_1 * integral_2  # 10.928
N1 = int(N / (ratio + 1))
N2 = int(N * ratio / (ratio + 1))

# Use inverse transform sampling in the following.
s1 = np.log(integral_1 * np.random.random(size=N1) + 1.0)
s2 = np.exp(integral_2 * np.random.random(size=N2))

samples = np.concatenate((s1, s2))
np.random.shuffle(samples)  # optionally shuffle the samples

plt.hist(samples, bins=int(20 * r_max))
plt.xlim([0, 5])
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following distribution:

[image: Example distribution]

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! So detailed and very useful. In order to fully understand why did you put the `+1` in the `ratio` parenthesis when you count the number of sample that we have to put in the left and right handside?

Comment: This is because `1` part comes from the left side and `ratio` (actually `ratio * 1`) parts comes from the right side. The denominator must be the total, since if we add `N1 + N2` it must equal `N`. So `N1 + N2 == N / (ratio + 1) + N * ratio / (ratio + 1) == N * (1 + ratio) / (ratio + 1) == N`. We have two conditions here namely `N2 / N1 == ratio` and `N1 + N2 == N`. By choosing `1` and `ratio` for the portions we obviously fulfill the first but now we need to normalize in order to fulfill the second. Here normalizing is done with the sum of the two parts `ratio + 1`.